# Type is missing the following properties from type, Typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have this error preventing me from deploying my website to *Vercel*, any help would be so appreciated.
normally I am receiving the *pageInfo* data from *Sanity* and being able to use in my website. Only problem is this weird TS error which is I don't know how to fix.

```
...
export default Home;

export const getServerSideProps : GetServerSideProps<Props> =  async () => {
  const pageInfo: PageInfo = await fetchPageInfo(); //pageInfo gives the error "Type 'PageInfo[]' is missing the following properties from type 'PageInfo': _type, address, backgroundInformation, email, and 9 more"
  const experiences: Experience[] = await fetchExperiences();
  const skills: Skill[] = await fetchSkills();
  const projects: Project[] = await fetchProjects();
  const socials: Social[] = await fetchSocials();

  return{
    props:{
      pageInfo,
      experiences,
      skills,
      projects,
      socials
    },
  }
}
```

here is the PageInfo interface

```
export interface PageInfo extends SanityBody{
    _type: "pageInfo"
    address: string
    backgroundInformation: string
    email: string
    role: string
    heroImage: Image
    name: string
    phoneNumber: string
    profilePic: Image
}
```

sanity file if anyone needs

```
export default {
  name: 'pageInfo',
  title: 'PageInfo',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    {
      name:"address",
      title:"Address",
      type: "string"
    },
    {
      name:"backgroundInformation",
      title:"BackgroundInformation",
      type: "string"
    },
    {
      name:"email",
      title:"Email",
      type: "string"
    },
    {
      name:"role",
      title:"Role",
      type: "string"
    },
    {
      name:"heroImage",
      title:"Image",
      type:"image",
      options:{
        hotspot: true,
      }
    },
    {
      name:"name",
      title:"Name",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name:"phoneNumber",
      title:"PhoneNumber",
      type: "string"
    },

    {
      name:"profilePic",
      title:"ProfilePic",
      type: "image",
      options: {
        hotspot: true
      }
    },
    {
      name:"socials",
      title:"Socials",
      type: "array",
      of: [{ type: "reference", to: {type: "social"}}]
    },

   ],
}
```

fetching pageInfo

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import { sanityClient } from "../../sanity"
import { PageInfo} from "../../typings"

const query = groq`
    *[_type == "pageInfo"][0]
`
type Data = {
    pageInfo: PageInfo[ ]
}

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<Data>
){
    const pageInfo: PageInfo[] = await sanityClient.fetch(query);
    res.status(200).json({ pageInfo })

}
```

...

```
import { PageInfo } from "../typings";

export const fetchPageInfo = async() => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/getPageInfo`)

    const data = await res.json()
    const pageInfo: PageInfo[] = data.pageInfo;
    //console.log("fetching => > >", skills)
    return pageInfo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type mismatch. In your `fetchPageInfo`, the return value is of type `PageInfo[]` (to be exact, `Promise<PageInfo[]>`). And here, you're treating the return value as a singular `PageInfo`:

```
const pageInfo: PageInfo = await fetchPageInfo()
```

Hence TypeScript's objection.

Comment: thank you for clarification. I was following a youtube tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urgi2iz9P6U&ab_channel=SonnySangha) where he did it like this. Then I try to fix it before as you said but that was causing a lot of other problems too. Then I figured all of them after 2 days and finally deployed the app. There was a lot of problems that Tutor is not pointing and when I made a comment in the video explaining everything and showing the solutions, he deleted my comment. (btw to see the tutor's code you have to pay) so eventually here is an another situation money talks first.